# A boolean variable named "mMainStack" in ActivityServiceManager, what is it used for?

Tags: android

There is a boolean variable in ActivityServiceManager.java named mMainStack. I wonder whether it is used as a debug flag. if not, what is it used for? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I answer it myself. The variable mMainStack is always true in every each Android source code. The google engineers want to use activitystack to manage activity information so that they define a boolean varaible to diff it in ams with others. But they don't make that sense. So there is only one activitystack, in ams, which  is always true.